# AutoDesk Forge Data Management version API endpoint not returning OSS storage id for .f2d file

Tags: autodesk-forge

I want to get the OSS storage Urn of a drawing file (.f2d) related to a fusion design file (.f3d) file

https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/:project_id/versions/:version_id/refs

I am making a request to the above endpoint with the version id of the (.f3d file) and the response has the drawing file (.f2d) version id

By using this version id of the (.f2d) file. I make a request to the endpoint below

https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/:project_id/versions/:version_id

but apparently the response does not have have the OSS storage data in the response

relationships.storage is missing when I make request for drawing file (.f2d)

"storage": {
"data": {
"type": "objects",
"id": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/7d403ee2-b954-4cc7-a96e-755e5e4b2005.f3d"
},
"meta": {
"link": {
"href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/7d403ee2-b954-4cc7-a96e-755e5e4b2005.f3d?scopes=global"
}
}
}